# SQL: return additional column from inner join subquery with 2 tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given the following 2 tables:

```
PROJ_CUSTOM                                PSR_FINAL_DATA
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

PROJ_ID          PROJ_NAME                 PROJ_ID             ACCT_ID

61000.001.ABC    Accounting                61000.001.ABC       610-10-23
61000.001.ABD    Marketing                 61000.001.ABD       610-20-23
61000.001.ABE    Applications              61000.001.ABE       610-30-23
61000.001.ABF    HR                        61000.001.ABF       610-40-23
61000.001.ABG    Foo                       61000.001.ABG       610-50-23
61000.001.ABC    Accounting                61000.001.ABC       610-10-23
61000.001.ABD    Marketing                 61000.001.ABD       610-20-23
61000.001.ABE    Applications              61000.001.ABE       610-30-23
61000.001.ABF    HR                        61000.001.ABF       610-40-23
61000.001.ABG    Foo                       61000.001.ABG       610-50-23
```

And the following sql:

```
SELECT  PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME
FROM    DELTEK.PROJ_CUSTOM
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  PROJ_ID AS Project
FROM    DELTEK.PSR_FINAL_DATA
GROUP BY PROJ_ID
) FinalDb
ON      FinalDb.Project = PROJ_ID
WHERE   PROJ_ID LIKE '61000.001.[A-Z]%';
```

The sql returns the columns PROJ_ID, and PROJ_NAME.

How would I be able to add the ACCT_ID column from table 2 (PSR_FINAL_DATA)?

Comment: Is ACCT_ID always the same for each PROJ_ID?

Comment: Just looked at the db...yes seems like it's always the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as ACCT_ID is always the same for each PROJ_ID you can try this:

```
SELECT  Custom.PROJ_ID, Custom.PROJ_NAME, FinalDb.ACCT_ID
FROM    DELTEK.PROJ_CUSTOM Custom
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  DISTINCT PROJ_ID, ACCT_ID
FROM    DELTEK.PSR_FINAL_DATA
) FinalDb
ON      FinalDb.PROJ_ID = Custom.PROJ_ID
WHERE   Custom.PROJ_ID LIKE '61000.001.[A-Z]%';
```

Comment: Yep, this is most correct answer for my question. Thanks, Mike.

Answer (score 0):

Make it return ACCT_ID too. You are only returning PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME here :

SELECT  PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME. Include ACCT_ID there and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME,ACCT_ID
FROM    DELTEK.PROJ_CUSTOM
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  PROJ_ID AS Project,ACCT_ID
FROM    DELTEK.PSR_FINAL_DATA
GROUP BY PROJ_ID
) FinalDb
ON      FinalDb.Project = PROJ_ID
WHERE   PROJ_ID LIKE '61000.001.[A-Z]%';
```

Comment: you can not select ACC_ID because its not included in inner query's group by clause

Comment: you can not select a field which not included in group by clause, or aggregate function

Answer (score 0):

When you are grouping by Proj_ID you can only add aggregate function on ACCT_ID to return, first of all I can't understand why you are using group by, can't you just use simple select as below

```
SELECT  PROJ_ID, PROJ_NAME FROM    DELTEK.PROJ_CUSTOM
INNER JOIN 
(
SELECT  PROJ_ID,ACC_ID
FROM    DELTEK.PSR_FINAL_DATA
) FinalDb
ON      FinalDb.Project = PROJ_ID
WHERE   PROJ_ID LIKE '61000.001.[A-Z]%';
```